# Correct REST endpoint design when dealing with messaging

Tags: rest, endpoint

I'm struggling to work out the correct REST endpoints for a certain situation. On my website it's possible for users to send messages to each other. One user is able to send messages to multiple recipients.

I think that /v1/users/123/messages would return all messages that have been sent to user 123

What end point should I use for messages that user 123 has sent?

My database structure is as follows...

**accounts table**

```
id              INT
username        VARCHAR(64)
```

**messages table**

```
id              INT
account_id      INT            <!-- This is the senders account ID
subject         VARCHAR(128)
message         TEXT
```

**messagerecipients table**

```
id              INT
message_id      INT
account_id      INT            <!-- This is the recipients account ID
```

The messages table defines a one-to-one relationship between a message and its sender

The messagerecipients table defines a many-to-many relationship between messages and their recipients

---

Also I'm reading through [a PDF on API design](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf) at the moment which seems to suggest I should hide this kind of complexity behind the query string.

For instance....

```
/v1/emails?filter=author_id(123)
/v1/emails?filter=recipient_id(123)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect

```
/v1/users/123/messages
```

to return **all** the messages that belongs to this user. This means received, sent, deleted, tagged, drafted etc.

To specify a **subset** of a resource you can go two ways with this like you and bertvh stated:

**Querystring:**
I find it perfectly valid for filtering as e.g.

```
/v1/users/123/messages?type=received&folder=important
```

**Or as a subresource:**
Use this if you expect to have a lot of filter options on a higher level e.g.

`/v1/users/123/messages/received?folder=important`

As you can see this would reduce a filter option.

And like bertvh stated, the underlying database schema is irrelevant for serving the responses.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

To get all messages sent by a user:

```
/v1/users/123/sent
```

To get all messages received by a user:

```
/v1/users/123/inbox
```

Your database structure is irrelevant for the resource scheme but it can influence the payload structure. If you want to use JSON a message could look something like this:

```
{
  sender: 123,
  receivers: [124, 125]
  content: "My message content"
}
```